# Calling a method dynamically

Tags: javascript, string, firefox-addon, eval

I have a problem when trying to call a specific method dynamically. The problem is bigger, but I will try to explain simply. I have a manager with some functions, and I need to execute one of them by using eval (doesn't matter why, I just need to use it). So, I have:

```
function Manager(){};
Manager.prototype.loadApp = function(src){
    eval("this.loadBlueApp(" + src + ");");
}
Manager.prototype.loadBlueApp = function(src){
    alert("Great! " + src);
}
```

But when I call loadApp with "Blue" parameter, I need to execute loadBlueApp().

```
var man = new Manager();
man.loadApp("You can call me 'Looloo'");
```

But every time I try to execute it, it thows me this error:
missing ] after element list

I can make it work by adding single quotes in the parameters area, but if the string contains any single quote, it throws error (and it is a requisite not to change that string).

```
eval("this.loadBlueApp('" + src + "');");
```

I really can't change what the String src contains. Sometimes the string contains double or single quotes, and sometimes both.

So, I really don't know what to do. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S49MX/6/

Comment: why do you use `eval`?

Comment: `(doesn't matter why, I just need to use it)` - so far, I see no reason why you need to use it. `I have a problem when trying to call a specific method dynamically` - you don't need `eval` for that

Comment: You don't need use `eval`. Use `this.loadBlueApp.call(this, src )`

Comment: @hindmost you almost dont have to use `.call` : `this.loadBlueApp(src )`

Comment: It seems to me you simply failed to understand your problem can be solved without eval. Rare is the case where its use is necessary, really rare, and you should avoid using it at all costs. eval is dangerous and ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use eval!**
Since you tagged this [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) this goes double! The addons.mozilla.org website will reject add-ons that use `eval` unnecessarily.

What you want is just:

```
Manager.prototype.loadApp = function(src){
    this.loadBlueApp(src);
};
```

You since wrote that the function name might be in parameter and not static. Then use

```
Manager.prototype.loadApp = function(functionName, src){
    this[functionName](src);
};
```

to make it possible to call it like `manager.loadApp("loadBlueApp", "something");`

Or even:

```
Manager.prototype.loadApp = function(functionName, src){
    this["load" + functionName](src);
};
```

to make it possible to call it like `manager.loadApp("BlueApp", "something");`

Or per @Havenard just set `loadApp` appropriately:

```
Manager.prototype.setApp = function(functionName) {
  this.loadApp = this[functionName];
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ78H/) demonstrating all of the above.

PS: If you really have for whatever reason to `eval`uate something in a Firefox add-on, do so in a constraint `Components.Sandbox`/`Components.evalInSandbox`.

There is actually [a whole article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_C%3a_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons) (which is based on Wladimir's [Five wrong reasons to use eval() in an extension](https://adblockplus.org/blog/five-wrong-reasons-to-use-eval-in-an-extension) article).

Comment: I suppose `Manager.prototype.loadApp = Manager.prototype.loadBlueApp` would do just fine too. `Manager.prototype.loadApp` can be pointed to any function on the run with no need to implement anything at all.

Comment: @Havenard Yeah that might work, or not. The question unfortunately is not precise enough to know it it would be sufficient.

Comment: I have the impression this might be just what he really wants. Aparently he wants `loadApp` to route to the "real" loadApp function depending on what theme is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not gonna comment on the use of eval since you said *"doesn't matter why, I just need to use it"*. But here, let interpret your current eval :

```
eval("this.loadBlueApp(" + src + ");");
```

will result by doing :

```
this.loadBlueApp(You can call me 'Looloo');
```

There is a syntaxe error here. You also need to add the quote to pass a string as parameter :

```
eval("this.loadBlueApp(\"" + src + "\");"); //Note the escaped quotation
```

This will result to an interpretation of

```
this.loadBlueApp("You can call me 'Looloo'");
```

No syntax errors.

It might be interesting to escape quotation mark so it prevent closing strings error :

```
eval("this.loadBlueApp(\"" + src.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + "\");");
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nLuZB/

Comment: Hi Karl! I really can't change what the String contains (so I can't use replace). Sometimes the string contains double or single quotes, and sometimes both. So I can't change this way

Comment: @gal007 Which string you can't change? the eval or the argument passed to the function?

Comment: Both. I don't know the full name of the methos to call so I need to use eval. Part of the name of the method is in a parameter, so I need to use eval because it changes frequently. I didn't put this in the explanation in order to simplify. The text contained in the src var is JS code that need to be executed by the method, and that code is not always the same. So I can't predict what src will contain, I just need to pass it as parameter. I did it as a global var, but I would like to find a way to do it ptoperly as parameter.

Comment: I can't give a live example, it is too complex. Just imagine src can contain any character, so you can't predict what's coming and you can't just change the quotes of your eval. Don't imagine the problem of calling the method, it's not the important thing

Comment: Imagine this is like a Greasemonkey: it will execute the code of any user, so you can't predict what "src" will contain.

Comment: @gal007 Really, with no example of what could happen, no fiddle, I can't really help. I don't even know what I can change or not.

Comment: @gal007 You said `Part of the name of the method is in a parameter, so I need to use eval because it changes frequently` - you don't need `eval` for changing method names. You can access a dynamic method name like `this["method" + SOME_VAR](SOME_ARGUMENT);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch your quotation marks in your end `eval` statement. I changed the order of double/single quotes on your jsfiddle and it worked:

```
try{
    function Manager(){};
    Manager.prototype.loadApp = function(src){
        return eval("this.loadBlueApp('" + src + "');");
    }
    Manager.prototype.loadBlueApp = function(src){
        alert("Great! " + src);
    }

    var man = new Manager();
    man.loadApp('You can call me "Looloo"');

}catch(err) {
    alert(err.message); //missing ] after element list
```

When I looked, you had `'Looloo'` in single quotes, which was terminating your string in `'" + src + "'`

Also, I know others have said this, and I know this isn't what you want to hear... but you probably don't need to use `eval` for whatever you're doing. Without digging into your actual problem, I can tell you there are a number of other options. One might be to store functions (or objects) in an object and reference by a key.

`myFuncs[key]();`

or

`myObjs[key].loadApp();`

Comment: Hi Mike! I really can't change what the String contains. So this is not valid. Sometimes the string contains double or single quotes, and sometimes both. So I can't change this way

Comment: Then you'll need to do a replace on it to escape the quotes: `src.replace(/"/g, '\\"')`

Comment: I need to use eval because there are a lot of methods to call, it will change dynamically according to some parameters. So, the use of eval is a requisite and I can't change it.

Comment: Well, I'm not gonna argue with you since I don't know the whole problem, but that basically sounds like whole reason why we have concepts in OOP like inheritance, polymorphism, etc.

Comment: I really don't understand your point... It's not a OO problem, I just have some rules to respect: I can't predict what src contains and I can't call the method without eval because part of the name of the method is passed by parameter (I didn't explain that in order to simplify, I don't think the use of eval is in discussion, assume it has to be done this way)

Comment: @gal007 I think the point is that if you **"need"** to use `eval`, you're probably doing something wrong. Whether that be because you don't know how do it a different way, or because you structured your program in a weird way. But you should read these answers/comments for alternatives to `eval`. Or at least understand that the suggested `src.replace(/"/g, '\\"')` will work

Comment: Yea the replace suggestion works fine, I tested it. I don't understand the "I can't change the string" requirement. If you have no idea what the string will contain, then you at least have to do some basic sanitization on it if you want to be able to guarantee you will be able to concatenate it to another string and eval it. I don't see another option, and it's hard to imagine how this could be an issue.